# GridView column with checkbox field with SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have GridView with 2 columns.

The first column is: test-label (TemplateField)

The second: checkbox (asp:CheckBoxField) that connect to sql table with bit column (done).

I want that on page load - the page will check every row, where the checkbox = true, the test-label.visble will be false.

I know how to write code with SELECT statement to check the value from the SQL table, but don't know how to check every row on the gridview on the page-load.

how can I do that?

(i can't use findcontroll for the checkbox because it's checkboxfield and not just "checkbox".

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="done" SortExpression="done" HeaderText="done?" />
```

so, what can I do here? maybe to replace that field with regular cb? (i don't know how to do there databind - on the regular cb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [GridView.RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

so you can do something like

```
 protected void GVRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            var check = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("ID"); // ID is id of the checkbox
            var lable = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("LableID");
            if(check != null && lable != null)
            {
                if(check.Checked)
                {
                    lable.Visible = false;
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: +1 for null checking...I still think it would be good to check `e.Row.RowType` just for posterity.

Comment: the CheckBoxField dont have id atribute. i'm using: <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="done" SortExpression="done" HeaderText="done?" /> what i can to do for the findcontrol ?

Comment: i've found the solution.. simple.. just to do regular cb with Eval and your code is perfect. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in `Page.Load` because the `GridView` isn't databound yet.

Try handling `GridView.RowDataBound`.

Code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("checkbox");
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("test-label");
        lbl.Visible = !(cb.Checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: the CheckBoxField dont have id atribute. i'm using: 

<asp:CheckBoxField  DataField="done" SortExpression="done" HeaderText="done?" />

what i can to do for the findcontrol ?